# How to get lines that contain string in a file?

Tags: linux, search, strings

In Linux, How do I display lines that contain a string in a text file, such as:

```
search "my string"  file_name
```

How do I make the search case sensitive/insensitive?
And how do I also display the line numbers?

Regards

Answer (score 23, accepted):

well

```
grep -n "my string" file_name
```

will do for your particular query. GREP is by default case sensitive in nature and to make it case insensitive you can add -i option to it.  The `-n` option displays the line numbers.  For other myriad options, I recommend

```
man grep
```

for more interesting pattern matching capability of GREP.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $HOME/Desktop
s=xda
m=$(grep -n "$s" $HOME/Desktop/tt.txt )
if [ "$m" = "$s" ] ;then
    echo "success"
else
  echo "fail"
fi
```

Comment: Looks like this is wrong answer.

Comment: Also, single letter variable names are bad.  This code snippet would be much more readable with better naming.